# c++ smtp response value < 550 how to get the reply from receiver when the server have a delay

Tags: c++, linux, email, smtp, qt5

i use a little program in Linux Qt5 c++ derived from "Qt Simple Mail" project. I add some void and I need to enter all the email addresses with a bad server replies.
As I understand typically all these reply value: 220, 250, 234, 235, 334, 354 is only server response for manage the message, all other is bad reply. Bad reply means the email adress is not valid, the mail adress of sender is put on spam folder by the receiver etc etc. I need to save all these email adress to a file.

My first solution is these:

```
else
{
    // something broke.

    QString rsp1 = response;
    QByteArray ba = rsp1.toLatin1();
    const char *c_rsp2 = ba.data();
    state = Close;
    emit status( tr( "Failed to send message" ), tr(c_rsp2));
}
```

status originally it was a signal with only one value, I added another one, a second QString to signal from a QMessageBox from the mainwindow the problem .... on the mainwindow in the signal management I did so:

```
    else if ((stat == "Failed to send message") && isCvs&& user_mail.isEmpty() && (counter < (user_mail.size() - 1)))
{

    QString FakeAdress = user_mail[counter];
    ui->indirizziNO->appendPlainText(FakeAdress);

    QFile MailError("/home/con/MAR/MailError.txt");
    if(!MailError.open(QIODevice::Append)){
        qDebug() << " error file not exist";
        return;
    }
    else{
        QTextStream out(&MailError);
            out << user_mail[counter]+"\n\n";
            MailError.flush();
            MailError.close();
    }

    counter++;
    QString sno = QString::number(counter);
    ui->ContInvi->setText(sno);
    QMessageBox *mbox3 = new QMessageBox();
    mbox3->setWindowTitle(tr("Messages Sender"));
    mbox3->setText("Unexpected reply from SMTP server:\n\n" + err);
    mbox3->show();
    QTimer::singleShot(3000, mbox3, SLOT(hide()));
    QTimer::singleShot(15000, this, SLOT(sendMail()));
}
```

these work ... but if the server have some delay the mechanism not work properly and some mail is not saved into MailError.txt ..... so currently if the answer is correct, everything ends well and the address is saved in the file ... otherwise not.

Is there a way to intercept late responses?

as it is obvious I do not know well the response mechanisms of the mail servers so I do not know where to go to get information to solve the problem.

thanks for any indication.

bkt

Comment: Would you please add a link to the *Qt Simple Mail* project on which your code is based?

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/archives/3.3/mail-example.html      \n                                                  https://github.com/xcoder123/SimpleSmtp_SSL_QT5/blob/master/smtp/smtp.cpp

Comment: I realize that the problem is realized after the connection with an email address is already closed. So you should use an array / vector where to put the email addresses with closed connection and find the way to take the error response that arrives with some delay from each email address on this array / vector / buffer .... but I do not know how to run the request to the server ...